# Jquery Exclude a checkbox from select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

My HTML code to select all checkboxes

```
Select All <input type="checkbox"  name='select_all' id='select_all'  value='1'/>
```

My Javascript code to select all checkboxes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#select_all').change(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
       checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
                } else {
        checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

The code works great and selects all the checkboxes, I would like to exclude the following checkbox from the selection (select all) criteria, is it possible to exclude the following?

```
 <input type="checkbox"  name='sendtoparent' id='sendtoparent'  value='1'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
$(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox').not('#sendtoparent');
```

Comment: ok sure, it's a method. still correct, no need to downvote just so your answer gets picked :P I'm just trying to help them get their stuff working

Comment: my apologies for blaming you, it just seemed strange. that wasn't fair of me

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can use `:not` or `not()` to exclude the element by its `id` attribute. From there you can simplify the logic by just setting the `checked` property of those checkboxes to match that of the `#select_all` element. Try this:

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
  var $checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox').not('#sendtoparent');
  $checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```